# Upgrade issue in gradle build tools version from 1.2.3 to 1.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've upgraded the gradle build tools from 1.2.3 to 1.3.1 and started seeing the following error on gradle sync. I had no issues with 1.2.3 version. I'm on gradleVersion 2.3. Is there anyway I can avoid this error?

> Error:Your project contains 2 or more modules with the same
>   identification com.salesforce.android:AndroidCommon at
>   ":AndroidCommon" and ":AndroidCommon:AndroidCommon". You must use
>   different identification (either name or group) for each modules.

AndroidCommon is one of the libraries that I'm using. I tried with versions 1.3 and 1.4 of Android Studio. Seems like the AS version doesn't matter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This kind of error happens in these cases:

- 2 modules have the same identification (group+name). [Check the code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/BasePlugin.java#665)
- 1 module has the same name of the root project

In the first case:

- rename one of the modules
- update the `settings.gradle` file with the new name
- run `gradlew clean assemble`

In the second case.

- rename the root project or follow the steps above.`

This check was introduced with gradle-plugin 1.3.x.
You can check the code:

- [gradle plugin 1.3.1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_1.3.1/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/BasePlugin.groovy)
- [gradle plugin 1.2.3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_1.2.3/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/BasePlugin.groovy)

Comment: Thanks Gabriele. My issue deals with the second case. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 modules with the same name as the error states change name of a module.

**To rename a module**

go to **settings.gradle** and rename the module to your new name. Then close Android Studio, and rename the folder using File Explorer. Now reopen Android studio and your module name will be updated.