# Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application'] > Your project contains 2 or more modules with the same identification

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

How can I find thses module?

```
enter code here


buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply from: "obb.gradle"

dependencies {
    compile project(":tests:gdx-tests")
    compile project(":gdx")
    compile project(":extensions:gdx-box2d:gdx-box2d")
    compile project(":extensions:gdx-bullet")
    compile project(":extensions:gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers")
    compile project(":extensions:gdx-freetype")
    compile project(":backends:gdx-backend-android")
    compile libraries.android
   }    

android {
    buildToolsVersion versions.androidBuildTools
    compileSdkVersion versions.androidSdk
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }       
   }
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'


 }
```

> Error:(23, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project
>   ':tests:gdx-tests-android'.
>
> > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
> >     Your project contains 2 or more modules with the same identification com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d at
> >     ":extensions:gdx-box2d" and ":extensions:gdx-box2d:gdx-box2d". You
> >     must use different identification (either name or group) for each
> >     modules.

Comment: Try see your second Gradle file. Maybe you write the same strings

Comment: post your settings.gradle and your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

In [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33530050/upgrade-issue-in-gradle-build-tools-version-from-1-2-3-to-1-3-1) you have a list of different steps to go through to solve your problem.

> This kind of error happens in these cases:
>
> 2 modules have the same identification (group+name). Check the code
>
> 1 module has the same name of the root project

Comment: Then how can I find the modules?

Comment: The modules are each of your projects. ":tests:gdx-tests" is a module, ":gdx" too...

Comment: After I changed the modules‘ name，another promblem occured：>Could not find method compile()